# Invalid Read size - Finding Command Line Average

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm trying to find the average of all the number added during command line execution. I'm getting some valgrind error of improoer memory allocation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int * arg2int(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    int i = 1;
    int *result = malloc (sizeof (int) * (argc-1));  
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++){
    result[i] = atoi(argv[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

float arrayAvg(int size, int *array) {
    /*STUB return 0.0/0.0; */
    int i = 0;
    float sum = 0.0f;
    for (i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    sum = sum + array[i];
    int avg = sum/size;
    return (float)avg;
}
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    int *array = arg2int(argc, argv);
    float avg = arrayAvg(argc-1, array);
    printf("%.2f\n",avg);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the Valgrind error,

```
==785== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==785== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==785== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==785== Command: ./out
==785== 
==785== Invalid read of size 4
```

I analyzed that I'm reading from a constant character array of command line entries into an integer array. But how to remove the valgrind error.
**Quick Note**
The program will execute correctly without any errors. I have tested it. This is just about understanding why the valgrind error rises.

**Sample Output:**

```
$ ./out 4 6 
5.00
```

Comment: You should check value of `argc` . What if `argc=1` ? Then you would allocate `0` memory . And you would dereference it leading to undefined behaviour .

Comment: `result[i] = atoi(argv[i]);` --> `result[i-1] = atoi(argv[i]);`

Comment: `i<=size`  needs checking

Comment: @BLUEPIXY can you post it as the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors: in the arg2int as @BLUEPIXY already mentioned

```
result[i] = atoi(argv[i]); --> result[i-1] = atoi(argv[i]);
```

and in the arrayAvg as @amdixon said

```
for (i = 0; i <= size; i++) --> for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

Now it looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int * arg2int(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    int i = 1;
    int *result = (int*)malloc (sizeof (int) * (argc-1));  

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        result[i-1] = atoi(argv[i]);

    return result;
}

float arrayAvg(int size, int *array) 
{
    int i = 0;
    float sum = 0.0f;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        sum = sum + array[i];

    return sum/size;
}
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int *array = arg2int(argc, argv);
    float avg = arrayAvg(argc-1, array);
    printf("%.2f\n",avg);

    return 0;
}
```